# ModuleNotFoundError while trying to use livewires and pygame for Python 3.6

Tags: python, pygame, livewires

I am using Python 3.6 and have succesfully installed pygame 1.9.3 and livewires 2.0.
I am trying to run the following code:

```
from livewires import games
games.init(screen_width = 640, screen_height = 480, fps = 50)
games.screen.mainloop()
```

And I get the ModuleNotFoundError:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame.image'
```

Code comes from the book "Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner, 3rd Edition" by Michael Dawson.
I tried to install different versions of the libraries but nothing worked.

Is there a way to fix this?
I'll appreciate any advice.

Comment: What does `import pygame; print pygame` print?

Comment: @BlackJack `<module 'pygame' (namespace)>`

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace.